# How to pass a value to backend with Node.js and Handelbars in the front

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I need to search in the database if exist a user passing a value. The value is asked in a input in the frontside. I need to pass the value in the URL.
Under my understanding the correct syntaxis is:
 `<a href="/donaciones/buscar/{{cedula}}" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</a>`
My handelbars section is:

```
        <label for="cedula">Cedula donante:</label>
         <input type="number" name="cedula" id="cedula" value="" placeholder="Cedula donante" autofocus>
     <a href="/donaciones/buscar/{{cedula}}" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</a>
   </div>
```

My js file section looks:

```
router.get('/buscar/:cedula', isLoggedIn ,async(req, res) =>{
    const { cedula } = req.params;
    const donante = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM donantes WHERE cedula = ?', [cedula]);
    
    if (donante.length < 1) {
        req.flash('message', 'Donante no registrado!');
        res.redirect('/donantes/ingreso_donantes');
    }else {
        res.render('donaciones/donaciones_ingreso', { donante : donante[0] });
    }
})
```

The problem if a click in the button the value "cedula" not pass and I get the error "Cannot GET /donaciones/buscar/" with the with the screen,

Anyway if I just write the nummber in the address bar it works perfectly:

*localhost:3000/donaciones/buscar/4----*, with this line in the address bar works perfeclty and get the correct user in the database and also return the value correctly back to the handlebars file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does `cedula` get passed to the view that is rendered (the one that contains the link)?

Comment: If I  understand your question, the value cedula comes from an input of the user, I need to pass this value to the backend to search if the user is saved in the database.

Comment: The issue you have described suggests that `{{cedula}}` is not available in your template where you render `href="/donaciones/buscar/{{cedula}}"`. To confirm this, we would need to see how you are trying to give `{{cedula}}` to your view.

Comment: Thanks @76484, it is true, you are right, the problem is this is not available in the template at the moment of submiting.

Comment: For that reason, it will be helpful if you share the code that renders this template. We need to see what values you are passing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved this? Thanks to @76484 I just understood that the solution was to put the code in a form and then send to backend with the post method and worked. See the code.

```
<form action="../donaciones/ingresos" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="cedula">Cedula donante:</label>
     <input type="number" name="cedula" id="cedula" value="" placeholder="Cedula donante" autofocus>
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
</form>
```